# Finding the gaps/holes in DEM

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.1

I have a SRTM DEM and need to find whether it has voids or gaps in the data.

Comment: No absolutely not. Just stuck with finding gaps in DEM of a basin.. I couldn't find any gaps when I see manually.. I wanted to make sure is there any other way to find Voids or Gaps.

Comment: What do you mean by a gap or void? Do you mean an area with a "missing data" code? For example, you might have a DEM where -9999 means "No Data".

Comment: yes how to determine  "missing data" in DEM?

Comment: yes missing data? is there any way to find out using raster calculator ?

Answer (score 2):

The DEM will have a **nodata** value that means there is a void (no information there). Load the .hgt file into QGIS / Arc, look at the layer properties, to find out what it is. Visually, you could:

- Make the layer completely black.
- Set the nodata value to be transparent (should be automatic).
- Look for voids.

Programmatically, you could

- load the raster to an array and
- count nodata values.